# How to check if a value exists in an ArrayList that contains an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I have an ArrayList that contains another ArrayList, and I'm trying to see if the inner Arraylist contains a value that I'm looking for. If it does, I want to return the index in which that array exists.

```
 List<List<String>> messages = parseMessages(extract.getPath());

        String needle = "test";
        messages.stream()  // Stream<List<String>>
                .filter(message -> message.contains(needle))
                .flatMap(List::stream)  // Stream<String>
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

So I wrote this code after I captured an ArrayList within an ArrayList.

The array that I am trying to access is "Messages" which contains 2 other arraylist.

I want to use the contains method to check if the inner arraylist contains a value and return the index of that arrayList.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
messages.stream()  
        .filter(message -> message.contains(needle))
        .map(message -> message.indexOf(needle))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The `map` stage returns the index of the value. This will continue for other lists even after matching inner list containing `needle` is found. To stop after the first match, you can use `findFirst`.

```
 messages.stream()
        .filter(message -> message.contains(needle))
        .map(message -> message.indexOf(needle))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

If you want to get the index of the *outer list*,

```
IntStream.range(0, messages.size())
        .filter(index -> messages.get(index).contains(needle))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Again, to stop after one match,

```
IntStream.range(0, messages.size())
        .filter(index -> messages.get(index).contains(needle))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Hmm, nothing gets printed out

Comment: Yeah I have that, i.e the bit from messages.stream() but nothing seems to get printed onto the console

Comment: What else you expect to be printed? Can you show the code/example?

Comment: Ok nevermind, so I am able to print the contents of my ArrayList, however, I was only able to do that when I removed the code for checking if the list contains the value stored in the needle. I can defintley see element that I'm looking for in teh inner array, but programatically it cant find it

Comment: I don't get you. See the updated code on Ideone. I have added code for printing.